# Alerta de e-mail - TFS Visual Studio

Tags: team-foundation-server, visual-studio-2010, alert

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma possibilidade de configurar os alertas do TFS, de acordo com a branch que foi alterada. Não tenho objetos em lock comigo, mas preciso acompanhar check in de determinadas branchs que várias pessoas alteram.

Por exemplo:
Alguém fez check in na BRANCH :

> $/guilherme/teste/2016

Um e-mail é disparado informando que teve mudança.

Pelo que vi no [alerta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yImt2.png) não tem nada referente ao que preciso.

Comment: Uso a versão:
Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, um amigo me explicou e é preciso instalar o Microsoft Team Foundation Server Power Tools. Após a instalação, vá no visual studio é só dar um right-click na pasta que você deseja receber alertas e clique em "Alert on Change".

Answer (score 0):

É possível fazer também pelo Web Portal do TFS.

1. [image: Relacionar o item]
2. [image: Relacionar o item]
3. [image: Relacionar o item]